# How can i add the publish version in a textbox for a VSTO Excel Add in . net?

Tags: .net, excel, visual-studio, vsto, add-in

currently i'm updating the publish version manually in a VSTO admin of excel. But i want to add the version as variable to avoid the manual stuff.

i have only found examples in C#. Does anyone knows to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I return the published version number and release date.

If you're running the Addin from debug mode, it will not be able to read the publish version.

```
Const dateFormat As String = "dd-MMM-yyyy  hh:mm tt"
Dim publishVersion As String
Dim releaseDate As String

If (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) Then
    releaseDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToString(dateFormat)
    publishVersion = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()
Else
    releaseDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(Application.ExecutablePath).ToString(dateFormat)
    publishVersion = "Development"
End If
```